# python key() error

Tags: python, linux

```
Environment: python 2.6
path="/this/is/an/example/"

cmd={'Foo': (PATH + 'sh forExample.sh'), 'blah': (PATH + 'sh secExample.sh')}

for app in cmd.keys():
    print 'app name', app
```

it prints as expected `Foo`

However, when I try to access 'sh forExample.sh'

```
   for app in cmd.keys():
        print 'app name', app
        run_apps([app])
```

where run_apps function looks like this..

```
def run_apps(apps):
        for a in apps:
                print a
                cmdlist = cmd[a][0]
                print cmdlist
```

It does not give the expected output, but instead gives `'s'`. I tried varying the value in cmd[a][x], it keeps giving the value of the character which X points to.

Oh and this was the error: `/bin/sh: 1: /: Permission denied`
I am using `Linux, distro: Ubuntu.`

any idea what the error is? where I am going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `Foo` of your `cmd` dict is `'sh forExample.sh'`.

So `cmd[a][0]` will result in the first character of that string.

---

Looking at this line

```
cmd={'Foo': ('sh forExample.sh'), 'blah': ('sh secExample.sh')}
```

it seems that you want to have a `tuple` as value in your dict. To create a one-value tuple, just append a `,` and your code should work as expected:

```
cmd={'Foo': ('sh forExample.sh',), 'blah': ('sh secExample.sh',)}
```

Now the value of `cmd[a]` is `('sh forExample.sh',)`, and accesing it with `[0]` will yield `'sh forExample.sh'` .

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're sending in the key but not the value. Try this:

```
for app in cmd.keys():
    print 'app name', app
    run_apps(app,cmd[app])
```

then run_apps gets:

```
def run_apps(a,app):
    print a
    print app
```